# different NSManagedObjectModel than this context's' CoreData SwiftUI error

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I just previously setup CoreData for my application to store some data. I originally had it working with a different entity, but soon realised it was the wrong model, and created a new entity and deleted the initial one. After changing the appropriate variable / object names in my CoreDataManager class, I keep running into the following error (a thread issue)

```
'The fetch request's entity 0x600001040370 'UserSettings' appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context's'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

To give some context here is my coreDataManager class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    
    static let shared: CoreDataManager = {
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate.instance!
        let instance = CoreDataManager(managedObjectContext: appDelegate.persistanceContainer.viewContext)
        return instance
    }()
    
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        managedContext = managedObjectContext
    }
}

//MARK:- CalorieTracker Insert/Update/Delete
extension CoreDataManager {
    func addUserSettingsData(id: UUID, firstName: String, height: Double, weight: Double, gender: String, age: Double, activityLevel: String, bmr: Double, completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let userSettingsEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "UserSettings", into: managedContext) as? UserSettings
        userSettingsEntity?.id = id
        userSettingsEntity?.firstName = firstName
        userSettingsEntity?.height = height
        userSettingsEntity?.weight = weight
        userSettingsEntity?.gender = gender
        userSettingsEntity?.age = age
        userSettingsEntity?.activityLevel = activityLevel
        userSettingsEntity?.bmr = bmr
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            completionHandler(true, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(false, error)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchCalorieTrackerData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        var progresses = [UserSettings]()
        let progressRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserSettings> = NSFetchRequest<UserSettings>(entityName: "UserSettings")
        
        do {
            progresses = try managedContext.fetch(progressRequest)
            completionHandler(progresses, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is coming from my fetch request, as the print statement get's executed when creating the entity in my viewModel:

```
import Foundation

class AddViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userSettings = [UserSettings]()

    
    init() {
       fetchProgresses()
    }
    
    //Creating the data
    func addCalorieTrackerDate(id: UUID, firstName: String, height: Double, weight: Double, gender: String, age: Double, activityLevel: String, bmr: Double) {
        CoreDataManager.shared.addUserSettingsData(id: id, firstName: firstName, height: height, weight: weight, gender: gender, age: age, activityLevel: activityLevel, bmr: bmr) { (isAdded, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Data has been added!")
                print(gender)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //fetching the data
    func fetchProgresses() {
        CoreDataManager.shared.fetchCalorieTrackerData { (userSettings, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let userSettings = userSettings as? [UserSettings] {
                self.userSettings = userSettings
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this error for quite a while now, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should make the init method private in CoreDataManager so you don't create a separate instance by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The issue to my program was that in my persistence file I was using the wrong name. Instead of using the CoreData class, I just used the project name. The correct one was:

```
container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CalorieTracker")
```